# Psycopg2 - COPY_FROM does not maintain row order

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a CSV file having 100000 rows. `COPY_FROM()` successfully inserted all the rows into the database table within seconds. But the row order found in database table is not similar to the row order found in the CSV file. Some of the rows in between seems to be shuffled. Did not find any solutions. Please help me out.

### CSV file

- R1
- R2
- R3
- R4

### PG table

- R1
- R3
- R2
- R4

Comment: There is no order without ORDER BY in your SELECT statement

Comment: Records in a database don’t have any intrinsic order. You give them an order with an `ORDER BY` clause when querying.

Comment: @FrankHeikens How do i specify order by in COPY_FROM() ?

Comment: @SalvinD'souza: A database (DBMS) can store the data in any order, there is no order. If you want your OUTPUT in a specific order, you have to ORDER BY something when you retrieve your data from the dbms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal and is to be expected. PostgreSQL inserts the rows wherever it finds room in the table, and when you query the table without `ORDER BY`, you won't necessarily always get the rows in the same order.

If you want your rows ordered, query them with an `ORDER BY` clause.